# Can I send a “cold warm wishes”?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Last day I took a picture on a high mountain. I want to post on internet for the Christmas wishes, but I’m very confused for the caption I want use to express.

Can I send “A cold warm wishes”?

Comment: Yes, you can make a joke with words that seem illogical but go together with your picture - in any language.

Comment: But not "a" when the noun is plural. Cold warm wishes.

Answer (score 0):

It's OK to do that. You're making a play on words:

> Sending you cold warm wishes on Christmas day.